# Python Tricks: The Book

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

> Still, string literal concatenation is a useful feature in some cases.
>   For example, you can use it to reduce the number of backslashes needed
>   to split long string constants across multiple lines:
>
> ```
> my_str = ('This is a super long string constant '
>           'spread out across multiple lines. '
>           'And look, no backslash characters needed!')
> ```

The above statement and example were mentioned in the book named 'Python Tricks: The Book' from Dan Bader. What does it mean? When executing `print(my_str)`, I get ***This is a super long string constant spread out across multiple lines. And look, no backslash characters needed!*** in the same line. Don't we need `\n` to divide the long string into multiple lines? Am I completely misunderstanding the above statement?

Comment: Have you tried it to see by yourself?

Comment: What do you mean *"correct"*? The literal itself is split across multiple lines, but the string's *content* doesn't include any line breaks. If you want a string literal that *includes* line breaks, look at `"""multiline strings"""`.

Comment: The point is that it's bad style to put enormously long string literals on a single line of your script. The PEP-8 style guide used by the standard library recommends a maximum line length of 79 chars, although many Python coders use longer lines these days, say up to 100 or 120 chars. The literal concatenation "trick" lets you split a huge string literal over several lines, and without messing up the indentation of the code block in which it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I think his point is that you do not need to create your string like this:

```
s = 'blah blah blah blah blah' \
    'blah blah blah blah blah blah blah foo bar puke broke joke enchanted kingdom' \
    'digital divide internet is a human right'
```

The author's point is that you can have a really long string with the code example. How you want to format this string, if you need to format the string, is up to you. You are free after all to change the code and do what you want! :)